# os.path.abspath from where is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

a newby Python dev here.

I have a json file in the root project folder `/json`

I´m using `os.path.abspath` to obtain the absolute path.

```
 abspath = os.path.abspath("json/quotes.json")
```

But it seems that depending from which class I execute that code is getting the path since that part.

So running my server, the absolute path return

```
******/app/resources/json/quotes.json'
```

And if I try from my unit test

```
*******/tests/json/quotes.json'
```

What I'm missing here?

Regards

Comment: Can you show us what the directory looks like?

Comment: From the docs: `Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function normpath() as follows: normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`. So it is essentially joining the current working directory to the path specified to build the full path. Instead you can look into [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: The path will be resolved relative to your current working directory.  You can view your current working directory with `os.getcwd()`.  Unless you change it in your program by calling `os.chdir(path)`, this will be your current working directory at the time you invoked your Python program.

Comment: with pathlib I have same result. there's no way to obtain just the absolute path where a resource lives?. point from my current location seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the file is relative to the location of script being executed.

In your case:

```
    abspath = os.path.abspath("json/quotes.json")
```

is equivalent to:

```
    abspath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "json/quotes.json")
```

The file may not be present at that location and attempting to open it may result in an error.

You could use an environment variable to set a base path and then use this in your script.

```
    # Set a default in an environment variable
    if not os.getenv('BASE_PATH'):
        os.environ['BASE_PATH'] = '/path/to/base'
    # Use the environment variable
    abspath = os.path.join(os.getenv('BASE_PATH'), "json/quotes.json")
```